# Generalizing a function to return a list of data.frame columns with invalid UTF-8 bytes/code points

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I recently wrote a function that uses grep and regex to find invalid UTF-8 code point (Since I work on a mac, my locale is also UTF-8). The input doesn't have to be UTF-8, as it is looking for invalid UTF-8 bytes. I wrote the function for work, and was wondering if anyone could provide tips for generalizing/catch any red flags in the code that I didn't notice (e.g. using base code instead of dplyr). Feel free to use any of the code if it's useful to you.

```
enc_check <- function(data) {

library(dplyr)

library(magrittr)

# Create vector of all possible 2-digit hexadecimal numbers (2 digits is the lenth of a byte)

allBytes <- list(x_esc = '\\x',
               hex1 = as.character(c(seq(0,9),
                                     c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))),
               hex2 = as.character(c(seq(0,9),
                                     c('a','b','c','d','e','f')))
               ) %$%
expand.grid(x_esc, hex1, hex2) %>%
apply(1, paste, collapse = '')

# Valid mixed alphanumeric bytes

validBytes1 <- list(x_esc = '\\x',
                 hexNum = as.character(c(seq(2,7))),     
                 hexAlpha = c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
                 ) %$%
expand.grid(x_esc, hexNum, hexAlpha) %>%
apply(1, paste, collapse = '') %>%
extract(. != '\\x7f')

# Valid purely numeric bytes

validBytes2 <- list(x_esc = '\\x',
                 hexNum2 = as.character(seq(20,79))
                 ) %$%
expand.grid(x_esc, hexNum2) %>%
apply(1, paste, collapse = '')

# New-line byte
validBytes3 <- '\\x0a'
# charToRaw('\n')
# [1] 0a

# Filter all possible combinations down to only invalid bytes
validBytes <- c(validBytes1, validBytes2, validBytes3)
invalidBytes <- allBytes %>%
  extract(not(is_in(., validBytes)))

# Create list of data.frame columns with invalid bytes
a_vector <- vector()
matches <- list()
for (i in 1:dim(data)[2]) {
  a_vector <- data[,i]
  matches[[i]] <- unlist(sapply(invalidBytes, grep, a_vector, useBytes =   TRUE))
} 

# Get rid of empty list elements
matches %<>%
  lapply(length) %$%
  extract(matches, . > 0)
# matches <- matches[lapply(matches,length) > 0]

return(matches)
}
```

Edit: Here's the updated code with the suggestions implemented.

```
enc_check <- function(dataset) {
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

rASCII <- c( '\n', '\r', '\t','\b',
           '\a', '\f', '\v', '\\', '\'', '\"', '\`')

validBytes <- paste0("\\x",
                     c(as.character(as.hexmode(32:126)),
                       sapply(rASCII, charToRaw))) %>%
  extract(not(duplicated(.)))

invalidBytes <- allBytes %>%
  extract(not(is_in(., validBytes)))

a_vector <- vector()
matches <- list()
  for (i in 1:dim(dataset)[2]) {
    a_vector <- dataset[,i]
    matches[[i]] <- unlist(sapply(invalidBytes, grep, a_vector, useBytes = TRUE))
} # sapply() is preferable to lapply due to USE.NAMES = TRUE
names(matches) <- names(dataset)

matches %<>%
  lapply(length) %$%
  extract(matches, . > 0)

return(matches)
}
```

2nd Edit: A better strategy was to use iconv. Let's say you have a file or object with some invalid bytes but that is generally UTF-8. This is often the case with Mac computers, whose default locale setting seems to be UTF-8. Moreover, Mac-based RStudio seems to use UTF-8 internally, and this can't be changed even if you set your computer's locale to a different encoding. Anyway, you can use iconv to sub all invalid bytes, normally displayed as hexadecimal bytes, (e.g. "\x8f") for the Unicode replacement symbol. Then you can search for that symbol and return a list of unique observations within a data.frame column with that symbol. Based on that, you can use "sub()" to replace those characters with the desired ones. One thing to note is that converting the file to another encoding, say latin-1, can have unexpected results if invalid bytes are present. When I did this, I noticed that some invalid bytes were converted to Unicode control characters, while other invalid bytes apparently matched valid latin-1 bytes and were displayed as nonsensical characters. In either case, I wrote a package to search data.frames for these characters and return a list, then do some replacement. The package isn't nearly as official as something off of CRAN, but if anyone's interested then here's a link to the repository: https://github.com/jkroes/FixEncoding. It's important to note that the "stable" version of the package isn't on the "master" branch; it's actually on branch "iconv". The documentation can be searched in R via "?FixEncoding" after installation of the correct branch, then finding the functions listed there and searching help for those.

Comment: Might help me understand how thos works in practive if you could demonstrate an operation on such dataframe with "invalidBytes".

Answer (score 0):

This will construct all the alpha-versions of the hex numbers to "ff":

```
allBytes <-  as.character( as.hexmode(0:255) )
```

Or as greppish patterns as you seem to prefer:

```
allBytes <- paste0("\\x", as.character( as.hexmode(0:255) ) )
```

The "special" characters that R recognizes does include the "\n" that you lissted but also a few more listed on the `?Quotes` help page:

```
rASCII <- c( '\n', '\r', '\t','\b',
             '\a', '\f', '\v', '\\', '\'', '\"', '\`')
```

You could create a vector of valid grep patterns for "characters" " space up to tilde ("~") just with this:

```
validBytes1 <- c(rASCII, paste( "\\x", as.hexmode( c(20:126)) )
```

I have concerns about using this strategy since my R throws errors when it tried to do greppish matches with what it considers an invalid input string.

```
> txt <- "ttt\nuuu\tiii\xff"
> dfrm <- data.frame(a = txt)
> lapply(dfrm, grep, patt = "\\xff")
$a
integer(0)

Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
> lapply(dfrm, grep, patt = "\\\xff")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : regular expression is invalid in this locale
> lapply(dfrm, grep, patt = "\xff")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : regular expression is invalid in this locale
```

You may want to switch over to `grepRaw` since it doesn't throw the same errors:

```
> grepRaw("\xff", txt)
[1] 12
```

Or may use `?tools::showNonASCII` as suggested by Duncan Murdoch when this came up on Rhelp 4 years ago:

```
 ?tools::showNonASCII
 # and the help page has a reproducible example of its use:

out <- c(
"fa\xE7ile test of showNonASCII():",
"\\details{",
"   This is a good line",
"   This has an \xfcmlaut in it.",
"   OK again.",
"}")
f <- tempfile()
cat(out, file = f, sep = "\n")

tools::showNonASCIIfile(f)
#-------output appears in red----
1: fa<e7>ile test of showNonASCII():
4:    This has an <fc>mlaut in it.
```

Comment: Overall, this is great (see my edit). I found that you need useBytes = TRUE when using grep() to avoid those errors, since R tries to evaluate the input string/byte and finds that it can't do so. Note that I included this argument in my code. That's why I constructed my patterns using two backslashes rather than one. I can't use grepRaw(), because I would need to manually type the single-backslash patterns rather than using as.hexmode() and paste0() to generate all the patterns at once. paste0() will throw a warning if "\x" is used because the escape character needs hex digits after it.